# change culture using wpflocalizeextension

Tags: wpf, localization, resources

maybe it's very simple, but how to change the culture in code behind to allow the wpflocalizeextension to show the desired resource?

I tried to change the application culture, but it did nothing!!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In order to change the current culture at runtime you use the following two statements. With `SetCurrentThreadCulture`, also the culture of the current thread is updated.

```
WPFLocalizeExtension.Engine.LocalizeDictionary.Instance.SetCurrentThreadCulture = true;
WPFLocalizeExtension.Engine.LocalizeDictionary.Instance.Culture = new CultureInfo("en");
```

To get a list of available `CultureInfo` objects, you can use

```
WPFLocalizeExtension.Engine.LocalizeDictionary.Instance.MergedAvailableCultures
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this?

```
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
```

Comment: This does not work when using WPFLocalizationExtension. The language does not get updated.