# WPFLocalizeExtension proper Folder structure

Tags: c#, wpf, translation, globalization

I am having issues with the already mentioned NuGet package. I have created a folder named **Resources**, where I have inserted the following files:

- Strings.en.resx
- Strings.sk.resx (my default language)

I am using Prism, where my MainWindow (plain container) is located under root window and all the other pages are located under `Views` folder.

I have added the following to my `MainPage` view:

```
         xmlns:lex="http://wpflocalizeextension.codeplex.com"
         lex:LocalizeDictionary.DesignCulture="en"
         lex:LocalizeDictionary.OutputMissingKeys="True"
         lex:ResxLocalizationProvider.DefaultAssembly="eManagement"
         lex:ResxLocalizationProvider.DefaultDictionary="Strings"
```

and here is an example of a TextBlock:

```
<TextBlock Text="{lex:Loc Key=Greetings}"/>
```

The problem is, that if I place the Strings.resx file in the `root folder`, the control is translated without a problem. But when I want to keep my translations under a `Resources` folder (meaning that english translation will be under Resources/Strings.en.resx), it suddenly does not work.

What do I need to change in order to make it work?

Comment: This isn't entirely clear from your question: You also have a `Strings.resx` file, so three files in total? You tried putting _all_ resx-files in the Resources folder, didn't you?

Comment: Yes, I have also tried to do that. However, the thing is that only the main one (Strings.resx) is taken into consideration and all the other modifications (other language mutations) are being ignored.

Comment: Two things you can try. First: Check if the build action for the resources is set to 'Embedded Resource'. Second: How do you currently set which language to use? You can try (for testing purposes) to set the language explicitly in code. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/35292059/1384848 how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I was missing the following line:

```
lex:InheritingResxLocalizationProvider.DefaultDictionary="Strings"
```

Plus in the code-behind I had to manually set the culture as otherwise my culture was always invariant

```
        #region Language Selection

        var culture = new CultureInfo(Properties.Settings.Default.LanguageSettings);
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture;

        WPFLocalizeExtension.Engine.LocalizeDictionary.Instance.Culture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
        #endregion
```

This has solved the problem.

Comment: I think the first line doesn't really do anything unless you change the actual Provider to `InheritingResxLocalizationProvider`, no? Probably the code-behind code was the real fix.